# Going to a UIWebView from an IBAction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, ibaction

I would like to know how do I load a web view from an "`- (IBAction) buttonPressed`" function.

Answer (score 2):

```
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

   -(IBAction)click

    {
        NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

        //Create a URL object.
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

        //URL Requst Object
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        //Load the request in the UIWebView.
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Jenifer.  However, your suggestion didn't work.  I was thinking I may have to load a nib. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Make the -(IBAction) load a new view, and put a UIWebView in that new view.

Comment: I"m sorry for asking, but what would the code look like?  I'm new to this and I'm still grasping concepts.  Thanks